# why this code always return zero?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] a=new int[256];
    System.out.println(a['t']);
}
```

i see **a['t']** in a script.wonder what that mean. I have try to excute the code. No matter what char I put in a['**t**'], it return 0, why?

Comment: This is crazy code. Why would you ever use a char for an array index in this array?

Comment: The first line will create a new array, which will have everything = 0. `a['t']`, `'t'` char type is converted to `int` type and we access the array at the ASCII code of `t` lower case, which is 0 since every element in the array is 0.

Comment: `a['t']` is equivalent to `a[116]` and not "put `'t'` into `a`". Have a look at an [ASCII table.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: `int` has default value `0` so you array will contain all `0`. `t` character ASCII code value is`116`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: No matter what char I put in a['t'], it return 0

The code you posted doesn't show you putting anything at all in a[].  All elements will initially be "0".

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] a=new int[256];
    a['t'] = 'T';
    System.out.println("a['t']: " + a['t']);
}
```

You should see something like this:

`a['t']: 84`

Answer (score 1):

this is because the int array is not initialized with any values, it is just declared with the size 256 so it is initialized to default value 0s impliciltly

Answer (score 1):

What you did is equivalent to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] a=new int[256];
    System.out.println(a[116]);
}
```

Because the ascii code for 't' is 116, so you are accessing to the position 116 of a new array of ints, and the default value for an int is 0, so all the positions of this array will have 0 unless you assign something different.

Answer (score 1):

`a['t']` is `a[116]` which is zero since by default java initializes the array content to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] a=new int[256];
```

the above code create array of integers i.e an integer is always initialized with 0 if no explicit value is assigned, like so if you have called a['T'] it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you access an int array with 't', but with 't' there it will be actually converted to an int first, which should be 116(the ASCII code of 't'), and then it means access a[116], and as you did not init that array all elements in that array should be by default set to 0, so you get that result.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object of Array of Integers, then Array is initialized to 0 by default (unless you assign some values to it).